# DeleteCases with a case as float?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, machine-precision

Might the `DeleteCases` have issues in matching when the list is of floats (machine precision numbers)? E.g. in this code it might fail to match correctly because float==float is not a good operation:

```
ClearAll[a];
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]
DeleteCases[a, Max[a]]
```

How would you handle this type of situations? What is the robust way?

Comment: In the posted example it will not fail because `Max[a]` is a member of `a` so it must match.

Comment: But might there be rounding issues somewhere in the `Max` that would cause the matching to fail?

Comment: No issues in this example. But if there were, the robust method is to allow some appropriate epsilon plus/minus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly faster method (30x for large lists) is to use Ordering and Drop:

```
Drop[a, Ordering[a, -1]]
```

This will always remove 1 element, even in the extreme rare case that the maximum value appears twice…